# Corriendo aplicación NODE.JS en un servidor real

Tags: nodejs, npm, hosting

Buenos días/tardes/noches a todos.

Tengo un pequeño servidor creado con Node que me gustaría poner a correr en un hosting ([www.1and1.es](https://www.1and1.es)), ya instalé nodejs y npm en el servidor, pero intento correrlo con node server.js y salta un error de 'segmentation fault' no sé esto a que pueda deberse ni cuál es la forma correcta de 'dejar corriendo' este servidor, agradecería si alguien pudiera orientarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: la manera permanente de dejar corriendo una instancia de Node es con PM2 http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Segmentation fault suena a error de sistema. si en tu pc corre  como corresponde, te contactaste con el hosting?

Comment: Gracias por el dato Alfredo Paz, chequearé eso.
Gracias por los enlaces @gbianchi, les daré una ojeada. Y no, no he contactado con el hosting, asumí que estaba haciendo algo mal, nunca he hecho esto.